# In magento How to collect order info in IpnController.php page

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-ipn

On magento 
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php
i need the order id in

```
try 
{

}



 public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            Mage::getModel('paypal/ipn')->processIpnRequest($data, new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that we need to update an another database with order info after the payment is done by Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this with a new order observer to capture the order details and do whatever custom logic you need with it. [The answer to this question should do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940743/execute-php-after-new-order-in-magento).

Comment: Any another solution?

Comment: You should not override core functionality, especially in controllers, if the end goal can be accomplished with a less intrusive method such as event observer. Can you provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve that would exclude the use of an observer?